# OpenCart 1.5.4: How To Remove Billing Details, delivery details and Delivery Method from Chekout Page

Tags: php, opencart

I want to remove Billing details from **step 2** , **step 3 delivery details** and **Step 4 delivery method** from the checkout page *`OpenCart 1.5.4`*.

User will pickup his order  from store. Just Need to display the message to user "Pickup from store" and gives facility to user select pickup date and time from `DateTimePicker`.

I will highly appreciate if i can get some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Opencart does not provide this kind of functionality. You need to hire developer for this solution.

Comment: @VipulJethva I am a developer can you please suggest me how it is possible?

Comment: Any solution for this question?